# Difference between setTranslationX/Y and offsetLeftAndRight/offsetTopAndBottom?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working with a `CoordinatorLayout` in which child views positions are being animated with the `ViewCompat.offsetLeftAndRight` and `ViewCompact.offsetTopAndBottom` APIs.

When a child view is added or removed from the `CoordinatorLayout`, the layout operation resets the position of each child to the top left corner of the screen, i.e. without any offset.

This [article](http://sentinelweb.co.uk/offsetleftandright-not-preserving-after-a-layout/) provides a solution, by setting a layout listener on the child view and restoring old positions.

I noticed that using the `setTranslationX` and `setTranslationY` APIs, this problem does not occur. Children keep their position after parent layout events.

How should I decide between these two sets of APIs for arranging my views on screen? I'm wary of using either without understanding their differences. I did not get a good understanding by reading the official documentation.

Answer (score 5):

Quite old question after many months I have few explanations:

First things first. Offset will move the view horizontally or vertically similarly to translate but it's used for permanent results.

When you use `View#offsetTopAndBottom(int offset)` then internally it has these functionality:

```
mTop += offset;
mBottom += offset;
```

On the other hand tranlate is an variable which is calculated in addition to this top/bottom/left/right positions and mostly handy in animations.

Both methods will trigger a layout refresh if needed.

More have been explained by Nick Butcher in this nice video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86p1GPEv_fY&t=5m42s

Regarding `CoordinatorLayout` are you by any change setting margins to the children? E.g. `BottomSheetBehavior` does not work well with margins since it ignores them. I think this might be the case for you.